# Tomcat Manager Authentication repeated popup while running a Java web project

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat-manager

I get a repeatedly popup to login to Tomcat Manager Application whenever I try running a Java web Project.

Putting in the username/password according to server properties (Manager-script) role doesn't work, the retarded server keeps popping up again with authentication required.

The server is Tomcat 8.0.27 with Netbeans 8.1
Suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create `manager-gui` role and grant it to the user in `tomcat-users.xml`.

```xml
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
```

By default Tomcat installs two applications `manager` and `host-manager`. These applications are in the `webapps` and they are using basic authentication mechanism to access their pages. Predefined roles above give access to these administrative apps. More about [Manager](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/manager-howto.html) apps you can find in the docs.

Comment: Thanks, was editing the conf file from program files but had to do of Appdata/roaming/etbeans/conf folder.All set now.

Comment: I had the same problem with a Netbeans 8.2 and adding an external Apache Tomcat 9.0.30. After guaranteeing that the correct user and pass are in the correct tomcat-users.xml and in the netbeans server properties, it still asked me for the credentials. When I cancel the credentials popup, the tomcat starts/stops without problem but the popup keep appearing. Only after I used the credentials in the popup,  Netbeans then updated one of its files with the user/pass ([user]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.2\config\Preferences\org\netbeans\core\authentication.properties) and the popup no longer appeared.

Answer (score 2):

You need create a user:

modificate **tomcat-users.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
    <tomcat-users> 
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/> 
    <user username="tomcat" password="password" roles="manager-gui" /> 
</tomcat-users>
```